# How do I grab each letter of a string in android?

Tags: android, string, android-edittext

I would like to create a small app, and in the app I have the user entering text in an editText. I already know the basics of editText, like how to get the text from it and enter it into a separate string variable. But after I have that string variable, how can I grab each letter of this message separately? I would assume that you need a For loop. Does anyone know of any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use can use a For loop like this:

```
String MyEditText = myEditText.getText().toString(); 
int len = MyEditText.length(); 
char chars[] = MyEditText.toCharArray(); 
for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
    //retrieve chars
  char newChar = chars[i];
}
```

Comment: Hello, Please see the comment for the other answer? Would this be a problem with this solution as well?

Comment: by default, String.toCharArray() does not skip/remove spaces - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray(). Have you  tested?

Comment: Just finished testing. This one does work perfectly. I am unsure what testing the others have done above, but my testing with the other solution does not work as they say. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
   //newChar is equivalent to whatever is at position i
   char newChar = inputString.charAt(i); }
```

Comment: The problem with this one is that it doesn't properly consider spaces in a sentence as a character. So in the message "Hi There" with the command inputString.charAt(3) would be equal to "T". And the message "Hi, There" would be " ". Is there anyway we can make it treat all spaces and punctuation as charachters?

Comment: @Takendarkk I put it to the test... Those are the results I get.

Comment: charAt(0) = 'H',
charAt(1) = 'i',
charAt(2) = [space],
charAt(3) = 'T'

Comment: Can you run it and post your results?